# Perl regex using array as search items

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I am trying to search a file for a given word and return the whole line.

If i specifically define the word such as below, it works perfectly however I want to use a array of keywords that can be used for the regex how would I go about doing this?

**The keywords used are from a text file stored as**

```
Hello
Cat
Dog
```

**They are called using the code:**

```
$words = '/computer/textfile';       
open(WORDS, $words);                
@wordarray =  <WORDS>;
```

**This works:**

```
while($line = <FILE>) {   
    if($line =~ /Hello/) {
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

**This does not work:**

```
while($line = <FILE>) {
    if($line =~ @wordarray) {
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($line =~ /foo|bar|baz/)
```

or

```
my @kwarray = qw(foo bar baz);
my $keywords_re = join('|', map { quotemeta $_ } @kwarray);
...
if($line =~ /$keywords_re/o)
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your example but the problem I have is that I cant use multiple keywords, a single keyword works fine. but i cant do multiple as it is treated as a single string. I planned to use multiple keywords which is why im using an array.

Comment: My solution indeed does work with multiple keywords (`foo`, `bar` and `baz`): if any of them match `$line`, the `if` body will be executed. Do you need something else?

Comment: @pts: The array example won't work as originally posted because it joins the keywords with `' '` instead of `'|'`. Fix that typo and it should work for the OP.

Comment: @user3423572 - Actually, won't work at all the way you are going to use it.